# ubuntu 16.04 can't start GUI

Tags: shutdown, lightdm, systemd-logind

I use command `sudo shutdown now` to shutdown the ubuntu 16.04 yesterday, but I found it's take too long to finish the shutdown process(about 3-5 minutes), so I forced physical shutdown it by power button.

Today I can't start it normally, when I turned it on, it's show a purple screen with nothing, I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> then using root user's password entered the `tty1`, found this error shows on the top of my command line:

```
systemd-logind[1391]:Failed to start user service, ignoring Unknown unit: user@1000.service
```

I typing `sudo lightdm start` and then I can use GUI normally, but there are some difference with previous GUI, such as I can't found `suspend` option in the configure menu. Then after I reboot, it's still shows the purple screen with nothing.

I found there was nothing changed in the `/etc/init/lightdm.conf`

I've also check the log of `lightdm` in `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` and `/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log`, but they are all empty.

I've tried `rm -rf /var/lib/lightdm/*` then use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and `sudo lightdm restart` but it doesn't work.

Finally I tried hide the `systemd-logind` service using `systemctl mask systemd-logind.service` and repeat every process I mentioned above, but it's make no difference.

How can I fix it ? I mean start the lightdm automatically and solve the warning.

Comment: without a log to show the error , the only thing i can think of , is if someone had encountered the same problem and can help you. Until then , you can write the command to load/start the lightdm in rc.local , or using a udev rule or creating a script in /etc/init.d and adding it to rc.d. Remember to disable/remove it after you fix it.

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou hi Pavlos, how can I set up the lightdm start automatically using rc.local or /etc/init.d ? Sorry but I'm not familiar with ubuntu.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwRlHU6dLDJQN202bTZ1R2wzN2c       in terminal do: sudo cp /<path to the script>/restart-lightdm.sh /etc/init.d
,then: sudo update-rc.d restart-lightdm.sh defaults             ,and restart

Comment: if its like you said and the command lightdm start is working for you, then it will load now on boot. if that doesn't work because rc.d is executed very early on boot, i will tell you how to make a udev rule. and i hope someone can help you soon.

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou Thanks!  Now lightdm can start automatically, still try to figure out how to recover...

Comment: nope. when it's time to disable that script, don't just go delete it. You first have to unload it/disable it before you remove it. just tag me again here in comments and i'll guide you. Cheers. I hope someone finds where your error is soon

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing it here too, in case someone has a similar problem.
Until the error is found and someone finds the fix for that, there is only one temporary solution.

[Download this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwRlHU6dLDJQN202bTZ1R2wzN2c/view) from my drive, i'm not deleting it until the problem is solved. 
Open terminal and do:

```
sudo cp /<path to the script>/restart-lightdm.sh /etc/init.d

sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/restart-lightdm.sh

sudo update-rc.d restart-lightdm.sh defaults
```

and restart

Comment: you can vote my temporary solution but don't mark it as a solution. I repeat it's only temporary until the error is found.

Comment: I have not enough reputation to vote for your answer, but your answer helps me a lot, Thanks !

Comment: I restart my computer but found this time it's can't open the lightdm I do what you said and found when I run this command `sudo update-rc.d restart-lightdm.sh defaults`, got this error : `insserv: script restart-lightdm.sh is not an executable regular file, skipped!`. So should I use `udev` rule as you mentioned?

Comment: no. udev executes after user login. so it won't help. the only way is using rc.d. But am i missing something ? wanna try open the script and add sudo at the commands and reboot ?  edit them easy using sudo nano /etc/init.d/restart-lightdm.sh

Comment: No, it still not work...I add sudo at ervery command in `restart-lightdm.sh`, which look like this now : `sudo lightdm stop \n sudo sleep 1 \n sudo lightdm start`, but when I run the update-rc.d command it still warning the error `insserv: script restart-lightdm.sh is not an executable regular file, skipped!`...

Comment: I add `\n` to make it more clear, there are not such `\n` in original file

Comment: haha now i get it. i think its like it sais. we just forgot to make the .sh executable. do in terminal : sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/restart-lightdm.sh

Comment: Are there any news? It happend to me!